Understanding the Role of Eigenvalues in Proving a Strict Local Minimum Using the Hessian Matrix
I have the following theorem:
Consider a function $ f : O \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ that is twice continuously differentiable on an open set $ O $. Also, consider a point $ \bar{x} \in O $ that satisfies the following two conditions

$ \bar{x} $ is stationary, that is, $ \nabla f(\bar{x}) = 0 $.
$ \langle d, \nabla^2 f(\bar{x}) d\rangle > 0 $ for all $ d \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} $ which means the Hessian matrix of $ f $ is positive definite.

Then, $ \bar{x} $ is a strict local minimum of $ f $.
The proof of the theorem starts with the following relation: Consider the smallest eigenvalue $ \mu $ of $ \nabla^2 f(\bar{x}) $. It holds that $ \mu \|d\|^2 \leq \langle d, \nabla^2 f(\bar{x}) d\rangle $.
Why does this hold? What do eigenvalues have to do with it? Is there any intuition behind it?

This is answered here. Note that the Hessian is symmetric. You only have to scale the vector $d$ to get a vector of length $1$.
